# Video4Linux Loopback Device on Linux4Tegera

Tags: linux, ubuntu-14.04, nvidia, firewire

I am interfacing Bumblebee2 camera with Nvidia Tegra TK1 board. I have installed firewire1394 driver along with coriander 2.0.2 to get the camera output and it is working fine. But I am not able to load the video for Linux module. I have installed the following two packages as well using synaptic

```
v4l2loopback-utils
qv4l2
```

I have following version of Linux kernel on Nvida Tegra TK1 board. 
**uname -a**

```
Linux tegra-ubuntu 3.10.40-grinch-21.3.4 #1 SMP PREEMPT Fri May 1 10:41:09 UTC 2015 armv7l armv7l armv7l GNU/Linux
```

I downloaded the stable version of  Video4Linux Loopback Device from [here](http://www.lavrsen.dk/foswiki/bin/view/Motion/VideoFourLinuxLoopbackDevice)

I follow the steps mentioned in the readme file and when I tried to make it, I got the following errors.

```
make -C /lib/modules/3.10.40-grinch-21.3.4/build SUBDIRS=/home/ubuntu/vloopback modules
make: *** /lib/modules/3.10.40-grinch-21.3.4/build: No such file or directory.  Stop.
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

I would appreciate if someone can help me to install video for Linux loopback device.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Current running kernel Linux tegra-ubuntu 3.10.40-grinch-21.3.4 does not have v4l2loopback support. I used module assistant to compile v4l2loopback module.

```
sudo aptitude install v4l2loopback-source module-assistant
sudo module-assistant auto-install v4l2loopback-source
```

Don't forget to mention the current running kernel headers. Then build and make v4l2loopback from [here](https://github.com/umlaeute/v4l2loopback)

Comment: What did you have to do to include the kernel headers? Did you use /usr/src/linux-headers-3.10.96-tegra (for L4T R24.2.1 for example)? When I try to build it cannot find the headers, even after I set KERNELDIRS to this location.

Comment: Now I have added the kernel headers I think, just by adding the files that the build was stopped by. Now when I run the auto-install, it says there is no rule to make target 'clean' and it stops.